# php domnodelist with array chunk

Tags: php, arrays, dom-node

I would like to use an an array chunk function with a domnodelist. This causes an error as the domnodelist is not a standard php array. Here is my code:

```
 foreach (array_chunk($nodeListArray, 2) as $chunk) { //each 2 make up 1 table

        $tableHTML='';
        foreach ($chunk as $key => $node) {
           $tableHTML.= $doc->saveHTML($node);
        }
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Thank you,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tableHTML = '';
$tables = array();
foreach ($nodeListArray as $i => $node) {
  $tableHTML .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
  if ($i % 2 === 1) {
     $tables[] = $tableHTML;
     $tableHTML = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_chunk(iterator_to_array($domNodeList), 2)` to create an array from an iterator